# Does anyone sell dragons scales or bones?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Where can I buy dragon scales? I completed the main quest line, so I don't think I'll be seeing anymore dragons, but I wanted to make some nice armor while finishing up the side quests.

Comment: I was attacked by so many dragons throughout the game, I had loads of bones and scales. Were you selling all of your off to merchants? You should be able to guy those back.

Comment: Merchants reset every ~2 in-game days, so no, you can't buy them all back.

Answer (score 14):

No, no one sells them, but you will [continue to encounter dragons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35553/can-i-continue-to-harvest-dragon-souls-after-the-main-quest-is-over) after the main quest line so you won't run out of bones

Answer (score 2):

## No

Dragon Bones and Dragon Scales are not sold by any vendor.

After you've finished the main quest, the random dragon encounters still happen

> and you can now call upon Odahviing to help you fight those dragons

You can still get Dragon Bones and Dragon Scales as well as Dragon Souls from those Dragons.

This'll allow you to create all the dragon armour you want, as well as unlocking all the available shouts.

Answer (score 1):

No, there aren't any dragon bone/scale sellers.

What you might want to do is go to those places where you are sure to find dragons.  If you are low level, change the difficulty to novice.  Each dragon gives 1-3 dragon bones and scales, no matter what type of dragon it is.

Comment: I have frequently seen dragons drop less than 3 of both scales and bones.

Comment: Yep, it seems to be 1-3 bones and 1-3 scales.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any dragon bone sellers, but you can go back to the word walls and there should be a dragon there.