# Where to sell Dragon Bones and Scales

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

There's a great question on [what to *do* with dragon bones and scales](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35297/what-can-i-do-with-dragon-bones-and-scales), and there's even a question on [whether you can *buy* them](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40551/does-anyone-sell-dragons-scales-or-bones), but the question I'm after:

***Question:*** Where can one sell those blasted Dragon Bones and Scales? Is there a list of merchants that will buy them?

Edit: I'm not looking for just *a* vendor, but preferably a list of vendors (as I've collected about 25 of the them). The ultimate answer would also have an indication of (approximate) amount of gold available on the merchant.

After some searching I found [a list of merchants](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Merchants_%28Skyrim%29) on the Skyrim Wiki, but that doesn't answer my question. The [page on Dragon Bone](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_bone) gives a little bit of info on selling them, but no clue on *where* to sell them.

My follower would certainly be very thankful for any answer to this question, as she's probably getting tired of hauling this loot around...

Comment: The workaround I found just after posting this is just going to one merchant that takes them, hit `T` a few times and wait 48 hours for the gold on the merchant to replenish, and sell all of 'em at the same merchant. (Felt like cheating though :D, but my follower's not complaining about that.) Still, I'd be interested to see if there's a list of merchants / answer to my original question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Any general goods store will take them: the two ones you'll hit early on are the [Riverwood Trader](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Riverwood_Trader) in Riverwood and [Belethor's General Goods](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Belethor%27s_General_Goods) in Whiterun. Others include:

- [Arnleif and Sons Trading Company](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Arnleif_and_Sons_Trading_Company) in Markarth
- [Gray Pine Goods](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Gray_Pine_Goods) in Falkreath
- [Pawned Prawn](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Pawned_Prawn) in Riften
- [Sadri's Used Wares](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sadri%27s_Used_Wares) in Windhelm

General goods stores, without the "Master Trader" perk, generally seem to have around 750 gold.

I just confirmed LessPop_MoreFizz's suggestion that apothecaries (potion shops) take them, too: [Arcadia's Cauldron](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Arcadia%27s_Cauldron), for example. Others include:

- [Thaumaturgist's Hut](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thaumaturgist%27s_Hut) in Morthal
- [Grave Concoctions](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Grave_Concoctions) in Falkreath
- [The Hag's Cure](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Hag%27s_Cure) in Markarth
- [The Mortar and Pestle](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Mortar_and_Pestle) in Dawnstar
- [Angeline's Aromatics](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Angeline%27s_Aromatics) in Solitude

Apothecaries, without the "Master Trader" perk, generally seem to have around 500 gold.

Beyond that, if you invest in the "Merchant" perk in the [Speech skill](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Speech), you'll be able to sell them anywhere you want, and if you invest in "Master Trader", every merchant will have a ton more gold.

The easiest thing to do is do a circuit amongst the general goods stores and apothecaries (or, if you have "Merchant" and/or "Master Trader", all stores in an area). By the time you're done fast traveling, you'll likely have spent 48 hours and can sell to the original merchant again. But if that's still not convenient, sell to a merchant, and wait 24 hours twice: (relatively) instant restock.

Comment: A number of Apothecaries will take them as well.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Good call: added.

Comment: I'd dispute that average gold held by Apothecaries number -  in my experience, they tend to have around 750, but I think that might be level based.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I just checked all the ones listed on my level 9/38 speech character, and everyone had a little over 500 (504, 510, 512, etc). It may indeed be level-based, but I've found nothing online about some sort of formula.

Comment: Guess your answer *is* the list then :D, thx!

Answer (score 3):

The Dragonborn DLC adds a unique merchant which can be summoned almost anywhere - the **[Dremora Merchant](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Dremora_Merchant)**.

Since dragon bones and scales are heavy, it would be useful to be able to sell those items without fast traveling, or without traveling at all.

According to the ["Dremora Merchant" UESP wiki article](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Dremora_Merchant):

> While he doesn't have a large selection, his gold count is always 2000 making him a good choice if in need to sell some gear to lighten the load immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to sell them to any general goods merchant. Far as I remember, alchemy vendors accept them as well.

Answer (score 1):

Any "GENERAL" store will take them. Some smithing npc's will take them off your hand. It is easy to go to whiterun as there are a couple of vendors that will take them of your hands.

Answer (score 1):

Go to belethor's general goods. he pays 250 for each dragon bone and he pays like 125 for each scale.... Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

if you are a high level in speech you can get a perk the allows you to sell any item to anyone

Answer (score 0):

join the thieves guild in riften, and Thillia will buy anything from you at a bargain price.
bones: 206
scales: 103
im level 19 nord