# Why am I unable to unlock my new shouts?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why am I unable to use dragon souls to unlock dragon shouts?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38593/why-am-i-unable-to-use-dragon-souls-to-unlock-dragon-shouts)

Why am I unable to unlock my new shouts in skyrim? I'm using xbox and currently have 5 dragon souls. The new shout is learned and the first word is greyed out. If I try to unlock it using "X" button to unlock a pop-up says needs a dragon soul to unlock. Please help, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't used all your souls?

Comment: @Flutter Except the answer to that question is "You're using the wrong button", and here the asker specifically says they are using X, which is the correct button for XBox.

Comment: @bwarner That argument has been made countless times, and the answer is always the same: Leave a comment on the other answer asking for an update. The correct course of action is *not* to ask a duplicate question.

Comment: Have you remapped your buttons? Many of Skyrim's UI screens won't update to reflect remapped buttons. For extra-special fun, remapped buttons also only works for some UI screens, so there are two ways that you and the game can disagree on what the right button is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to kill some dragons to get more souls and unlock new shouts.