# Console command dragon souls not useable

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Trying to make as overpowered a Skyrim character as possible (I am doing this out of boredom and though meh could be fun) I made a mistake and added all the shouts rather than unlocking (new to console commands, didn't realize they were different) so I added like 50 dragon souls with console commands, and can't use them. Help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things occurring that may prevent you from spending the souls:

- You added the shouts to your character (And they're already unlocked and as such you can't spend souls because you have no more shouts to unlock).
- If you haven't done the **Dragon Rising** Quest, you can't unlock the first word of Unrelenting Force (*Fus*). This also happens for all shouts that are *taught to you*, as in: you get them during the story
- You don't know how to unlock shouts. In that case, you have to open the magic Menu, click on shouts, and press **R** when you're over the shout you want to unlock. Spend the dragon soul. You can then equip the shout with **

If it's the latter it may be a duplicate of [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38593/why-am-i-unable-to-use-dragon-souls-to-unlock-dragon-shouts)